# how can i click a div with an css animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

My div has a `onclick` function , and my css has an webkit translate animation

```
<div class="ant animate" onclick="myFunction()"> </div>
```

my script have a console log  but doesn't trigger

```
.animate{
  -webkit-animation: food 30s linear infinite;

}
.ant {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background:black;
   pointer-events: none;
   z-index: 3000
}


@-webkit-keyframes food {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,1000px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,-1000px);

  }
}
```

my plnk is similar but with jquery http://plnkr.co/edit/Qv1T4t9thBj8EIpdJUSH

if i unbind my animation this click works perfect

Comment: look like ur code works..  Check plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/HjQXM7kIjgyOGpeYHCfe

Comment: this does not work for me, I browsed google chrome 30.0.1599.59 beta. the problem persists

Comment: Works in safari... both movement and alert. Does not work in chrome...

Answer (score 0):

The alert appears in the latest versions of firefox, and safari.

The movement works in safari, chrome but not in firefox.

In Chrome I get the following error:

```
    Refused to execute script from 
    'https://raw.github.com/furf/jquery-ui-touch-punch/
    master/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js' 
    because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, 
    and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I would say instead of linking to the raw.github address, download and host the file yourself.